# Calling out via Named Credential - API vs Token endpoint

Tags: apex, rest, namedcredentials

I created Named Credentials to authorize the api and got the token. Now i want to use the same end point to get the weatherdetail. when i tried to access same named credential then its showing error as invalid access token.

Token URL
http://XXXXXX.com/tocken

WeatherDetailUrl 
http://xxxxxx.com/zipcode

Any idea to reuse the named credential else i have to create another remote action and custom setting for this.

Code:

```
public string gettocken(){
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            Http http = new Http();
            request.setEndpoint('callout:WeatherAPI');
            request.setMethod('GET');
            request.setHeader('Content-length', '0');
  HTTPResponse response = http.send(request);
Map<String,Object> data = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
        return (String)data.get('access_token');
}

 public void weatheCall() {
        string token = gettocken();
          HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            Http http = new Http();
            request.setEndpoint('callout:WeatherAPI'+'/TX');
            request.setMethod('GET');
            request.setHeader('Content-length', '0');
            request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+token);

                HTTPResponse response = http.send(request);  **///Error {"fault":{"faultstring":"Invalid access token","detail":{"errorcode":"oauth.v2.InvalidAccessToken"}}}**
              system.debug(response.getbody());

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the FQDN and/or the relative URI of the token endpoint and your target API (WeatherDetailUrl) are common, you can define a single Named Credential and use it for both calls. This assumes that you're not negotiating the token in your Named Credential (authentication protocol is set to `No Authentication`)

Single Named Credential named `Foo` with URL set to `http://foo.bar.com/blah` will work if

- Token endpoint is `http://foo.bar.com/blah/token`
- Weather API is `http://foo.bar.com/blah/weather`

Apex code:

```
request.setEndpoint('callout:Foo'+'/token'); // token endpoint
request.setEndpoint('callout:Foo'+'/weather'); // Weather API
```

If the Weather API requires a token and the token protocol is [supported](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=5) out of the box by a Named Credential, you can implement it in a single Named Credential. This approach works even if the token endpoint and your target API endpoint do not have a common FQDN.